# What does it mean when Community completes a review item?

Tags: support, community-user

From the [Community user's bio](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community?tab=summary), I know that it:

- pokes old, unanswered/unaccepted questions
- owns CW questions and answers, anonymous edits, and downvotes on spam posts

From [this post](https://meta.superuser.com/a/4056/116928), I additionally know that it owns  the votes on CW questions/answers, all deleted posts, and migrated posts where the owner doesn't have an account on SU.

Imagine my surprise, then, when I saw Community reviewing suggested edits:

[image: community reviewing things]

This isn't new behavior, either; it's been going on since 24 February 2011.

I'm curious: what's the rationale behind Community reviewing items? Is there any sort of process that occurs or significance attached when Community completes a review?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a user decides to improve a suggested edit, the edit is marked as approved by Community.

Likewise, when the reviewer uses "Reject and Edit", the suggested edit will be rejected by Community.

Comment: Oh, and if a concurrent edit happens (a fully privileged edit is accidentally submitted when a suggested edit is pending), then Community will appear as the sole rejecter of the edit.